# Looping images through a button in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, button

I am trying to animate a button to periodically go back and forth between images. I have five buttons on screen, and I would like one after another for them to animate.

So far I have managed to change the image of the button to the desired second image, I attempted to put it into a `for` loop such as that displayed below, however came across an error.

I am new to iOS, and this is my first app that I am trying to develop.

Any input would be helpful.

```
func updatBtn(){
    delay(2.0){
    self.btn1.setImage(UIImage(named: "p2.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```

This is the code that i have currently used to delay the appearance of the animated image

```
    func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

I attempted to loop through the images with this for loop however received an error, the error was one regarding the fact that UIImages cannot be of type 'loopImages()',

```
func loopImages(){
    var imgArray = [UIImage]()
    for var x = 1; x <= 2; x++ {
        let img = UIImage(named: "p\(x).png")

        imgArray.append(img!)   
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to post more code, how is `loopImages` used?

Comment: @paulvs i was going to use the loopImages() function in the code as follows:            self.btn1.setImage(loopImages(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

Comment: The `loopImages` function doesn't return anything.

Comment: You will need to give the actual error message, the actual code you had when you received that error message, and the line which triggered the error message.

Comment: Are you just looping between two images?

Comment: @D.Greg yep, just looping between two images, its the same images for all five buttons on screen, however, i would like the first one to start and finish before the second starts to animate and so on.

Comment: @jcaron the error i receive is: !Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'UIImage?'

Comment: Have you thought about using UIViews with gesture recognition? Then you could loop an animation and fade between the images.

Comment: @D.Greg, thanks i will take a look, just found the documentation for it, it didn't occur to me initially. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html

Comment: @Prash1993 Give it a try. It's not that difficult. If you get stuck, post a question I'd be glad to help.